# jasmine 2.0 version of expect() in qunit

Tags: javascript, jasmine, qunit

In QUnit you can specify how many assertions are expected to run within a test
 i.e.
`expect(2)`

Is there way to do this in Jasmine 2.0? Though their docs are clear, I can't seem to find an exhaustive API list anywhere.

I would like to run multiple async tests without having to nest them. For example, the third test should reliably be last. But if the first two fail completely, the light is still green because `done()` is called.

```
it("Should run callbacks with correct data", function(done){

    //expect(3); //QUnit syntax

    test.fastResponse(function(data){
        expect(data).toEqual({a:1, b:2});
    });

    test.fastResponse(function(data){
        expect(data).toEqual({a:1, b:2});
    });

    test.slowResponse(function(data){
        expect(data).toEqual({a:1, b:2});
        //This should fail if the other two tests didn't run
        done();
    });

});
```

Comment: Could you add some psuedo code of some Jasmine tests to illustrate what you mean? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt example added

Comment: Ah, ok. So you are testing race conditions, essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding a `callCount` variable, and incrementing it by 1 each time a callback is invoked. Then you can `expect(callCount).toBe(x)` just before the call to `done()`.

On the other hand, you can use Spies to achieve this as well:

```
it("Should run callbacks with correct data", function(done){
    var callback = jasmine.createSpy("callback");

    var actuallyDone = function() {
        expect(callback.calls.count()).toBe(2);
        expect(callback.calls.all()[0].args[0]).toEqual({a:1, b:2});
        expect(callback.calls.all()[1].args[0]).toEqual({a:1, b:2});
        done();
    };

    test.fastResponse(callback);
    test.fastResponse(callback);

    test.slowResponse(function(data){
        expect(data).toEqual({a:1, b:2});
        actuallyDone();
    });

});
```